# Get same result on every system on spin wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I create a fortune wheel which is automatically spin after the interval of 30 second for now. But I am facing some problem in this and the problem is it should spin at same time at each machine. any body open this spin at any time it during its spinning time it should be spin and get the same result on each system

[My Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRLbgv)

Here is the auto spin code

```
setInterval(function () {

           var $r = $('.roulette').fortune(prices);

    $r.spin().done(function(price) {
    $('.price').text(price);
     $('.result_number_circle').text(price);

  });
    //  $('.roulette').animate({rotate: '+=10deg'}, 0);
    },30000);
```

Comment: You should have a server handling this

Comment: You need a server component as well then, which would be called by the client component, and all of the clients then get/see the same result. Otherwise, a sync solely based on client code is hard to achieve.

Comment: can you please show me any code sample please if possible @Exception_al

Comment: Look at this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax) .. a simple example to create a servlet ... make an ajax call and get data from servlet.